# How to pass ids to a keyup function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, keyup

I have the following code, for copying form values from one input to another when a checkbox is checked.

At the moment the values copy over when the checkbox is checked. But I would also like the value from the first input to copy over when there is a change and only if the checkbox is in a checked state. I am trying to use keyup to do this but I am having trouble getting it to work, where am I going wrong?

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function copy_fields_if_checked(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(':checked')) {
      $.each(event.data, function(key, value) {
        $('#' + key).val($('#' + value).val());
      });
    } else {
      $.each(event.data, function(key, value) {
        $('#' + key).val(' ');
      });
    }
  }

  function copy_fields_if_keyup(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(':checked')) {
      $.each(event.data, function(key, value) {
        $('#' + key).val($('#' + value).val());
      });
    }
  }

  var fields = {
    'input_1_193': 'input_1_191',
    'input_1_194': 'input_1_192',
    'input_1_29': 'input_1_22',
    'input_1_100': 'input_1_99',
    'input_1_119': 'input_1_108'
  };

  $('#choice_1_190_2').on('click.day-checkbox', fields,
    copy_fields_if_checked);

  $('#input_1_193').bind('keyup', fields, copy_fields_if_keyup);
});
```

My original code using.keyup:

```
$("#input_1_191").keyup(function() {
  if ($("#choice_1_190_2").is(':checked')) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#input_1_193").val(value);
  }
}).keyup();
```

This works but I would much prefer to pass in the ids into one function.

Comment: share your html and tell us exactly what you want. May be you will get a much better code rather than yours

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the advice - please see html here: https://jsfiddle.net/smithson_1/es0f8bs6/6/

Comment: Just to clarify - the idea is that the Monday fields are filled out then if you click Tuesday checkbox  then the Tuesday fields are automatically filled out. If you then go back and change the Monday values the Tuesday values will automatically update.